# sudo and Kerberos on AWS Linux issues

Tags: kerberos, sudo

We have an issue on some of our AWS machines, running Amazon's hacked Fedora/RHEL linux where newer-in-AD users can login with password but cannot autheticate for sudo.  Users that were created in AD a while ago have no issues and this does not seem to follow a pattern on servers (for eg. we created 3 servers at once from the same ami, 2 work, one fails).  The errors in the logs are of this format, starting with sucessful login via password:

> Jan 18 18:35:37 HOSTNAME sshd[24496]: pam_krb5[24496]: authentication succeeds for 'USERNAME' (USERNAME@AD.DOMAIN)
>
> Jan 18 18:35:37 HOSTNAME sshd[24496]: Accepted password for USERNAME from local_ip port 45236 ssh2
>
> Jan 18 18:35:37 HOSTNAME sshd[24496]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user USERNAME by (uid=0)
>
> Jan 18 18:35:43 HOSTNAME sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=USERNAME uid=10764 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=USERNAME rhost=  user=USERNAME
>
> Jan 18 18:35:43 HOSTNAME sudo: pam_krb5[24526]: account checks fail for 'USERNAME@AD.DOMAIN': user disallowed by .k5login file for 'USERNAME
>
> Jan 18 18:35:43 HOSTNAME sudo: pam_krb5[24526]: authentication fails for 'USERNAME' (USERNAME@AD.DOMAIN): Permission denied (Success)

I've double checked that the user didn't have a .k5login file, there was none, and adding one with only 'USERNAME@AD.DOMAIN' didn't change the behavior or the log messages.  I've also verified, as best as I can, that these new users aren't somehow different in AD, but I'm far from an expert there so there may be something else to check there if I knew where to look

thanks

Comment: Why are you using AD? Is this a mostly-Windows environment?

Comment: ARe the server's time all in sync?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - It's a windows-client environment with mostly linux servers.  We figured it was easier to get the servers to speak AD than the other way around

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins - all the servers are NTP-updated and pointing to the AD servers as time source.  I just double checked and they are within a second of each other.

Comment: It might be easier to have Linux clients!

Comment: @MichaelHampton there are other windmills to tilt at before that one

Comment: @amacks: What version of `pam_krb5` is in use? Is the problem eventually related to the users /etc/passwd position? https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0133096

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/krb5.conf` add this lines:

```
[appdefaults]  
pam = {  
       [....]  
        EXAMPLE.COM = {  
            ignore_k5login = true  
        }
}
```

where `EXAMPLE.COM` is your AD realm.

Comment: We've already tried that, sadly no effect